# Sublime Text misaligned columns

Tags: linux, sublimetext3

This is a screenshot of a code fragment viewed in Sublime Text 3 in Windows 7:

[image: Windows]

And this is a screenshot of the same code fragment in Sublime Text 3 in Linux Mint 17 (Qiana)

[image: Linux]

You might not believe but this little thing is bothering me since I started programming in the Linux environment.

Is there a bug with Sublime Text 3 columns alignment in Linux environment or it's just a matter of configuration? Is it fixable?

Comment: Are you sure both editors are using the same indent spacing and tabs v. spaces?

Comment: Although I have to manually change this behavior for every newfile I create, yes, both are set to indent as 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a monospace (fixed-width) font in the upper image, and a sans-serif (variable-width) font in the lower. Open up your font library program in Mint and find a monospace font you like (I prefer [Liberation Mono](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Liberation-Mono), but you may need to install it). Then, in Sublime, select **`Preferences -> Settings-User`** and add the following:

```
"font_face": "Liberation Mono"
```

(or whatever font you chose). Save the file, and you should be all set.